# How would I recreate this warped grid-like pattern?

Tags: bezier-curves

How might I warp a repeatable pattern along a complex curve like this (curve bending along the x, y and z planes)?

Notes:

- Not for animation
- Still image rendering

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a lattice object , and add a latice deform modifier to the object you want to deform. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html?highlight=lattice

Comment: is it a still image or is it for an animation? also, it looks 2D but you're talking about X, Y and Z? maybe tell a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried both **Surface Defom** and **Lattice** (as recommended by Susu). It looks like lattice is more convenient in your case as the cage can be simpler:

- Create your tile, subidive it a bit, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, array it, give it a *Lattice* modifier.
- Create a lattice, scale it in *Object* mode so that it contains the tiles, give it a bit of *Resolution* in the *Object Data* panel, but you can keep it flat on the W axis with a value of 1. Create 2 shapekeys in the same panel:

[image]

[image]

- Keep the second shapekey selected, go in *Edit* mode, enable the *Proportional Editing* option, move the vertices to deform the lattice, the object will deform as well. Once back in Object mode, play with the shapekey *Value*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped!